# A good tool for building admin / content management interface over MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, content-management-system, content-management

I'm looking for a good tool (or library or a framework) that I could use to easily build basic content management functionalities over MongoDB.

I am very well aware of the [Admin UIs listed in Mongo's website](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Admin+UIs), and I'm already using RockMongo for query and some db admin tasks. The problem is that while I as a software developer can happily use these tools, they are too powerful and complex for the people who are responsible for managing the content in the database.

So I'm specifically looking for a MongoDB content-management tool with:

- Ability to easily build (scaffold) user interface around collections (generated create, read, update and delete forms / views)
- Ability to add data validation and some template or schema for objects, especially when new objects are created and added into a collection
- Support for fine-grained access control (user groups, per collection and per object read/write/admin access)

I've been considering using [django-nonrel](https://github.com/django-nonrel/django-nonrel) for building one, but would like to get more opinions before going any further.

Comment: Curious to know what solution/approach you ended up using?

Comment: I'm still using RockMongo for the basic administration tasks. Also I'm in the process of writing an app-specific admin UI with node.js, express.js and Mongoose. Before deciding to go with them, I also tried RailwayJS (http://railwayjs.com/), which I found a little too bloated for what I need. Also the more I use Mongoose, the more have I become appreciate its elegance when dealing with MongoDB.

I'm pretty sure some Mongoose admin tool will emerge, but right now I need to get the job done so I'm back to lower level coding for now.

Comment: See also a related, newer question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11409819/admin-panel-for-node-js-and-mongoose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're looking for a solution beyond a straight Admin UI, I expect you will have to roll your own.  I went through a similar exercise a few months ago and ended up using [Yii Framework (PHP)](http://www.yiiframework.com/).

The attributes you're looking for (scaffolding, validation, RBAC, ..) are common to many frameworks.  Are there specific languages you would prefer/consider using?  There are frameworks/libraries for [Ruby](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Ruby+Language+Center#RubyLanguageCenter-ObjectMappers), [PHP](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/PHP+Libraries,+Frameworks,+and+Tools), [Python](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/tools.html#framework-tools), etc.  Many of these go to lengths to coerce MongoDB into an ActiveRecord/ORM pattern to enable use of CRUD and scaffolding.  An emerging approach for working with NoSQL data sources is the DataMapper/ODM pattern, which is a much more comfortable fit compared to ORM.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [penguin](https://github.com/etabits/node-penguin): a module that automatically generates administration pages based on your Mongoose models.